# How to decide when a user search is should be stored in the history?

Tags: android, user-interface, search, responsive

In my android app, I have a search box, it searches as the user types. Users request that I store their search history, but the problem is how do I know when a search is complete?

Some possibilities:

1. Wait X number of seconds after the user stops typing -- Currently I am using 3000ms timer, but this has problems, some users type fast, and others slower. This would store too often or not at all at times.
2. Do not search as you type, instead have a button that says "go" and store after the user clicks that button. Its easiest to implement but users will not like the loss of the immediate search.
3. Option 1 with some filters, min search chars and if the last history item is contained in the beginning of the current one it means its a continuation of the user typing, so replace last with current.

What is a good way of achieving something like this?

Comment: Another possibility is to save the text when the user selects a result maybe

Comment: @Ramin yep! but as with the others it is flawed, the app is a dictionary, so just looking at the result is enough, clicking on it is not necessary.